# Disable resizing tables in mozilla in design mode

Tags: javascript, firefox

Is there a way to remove the attribute '_moz_resizing="true"' added by
Firefox from <TABLE> to avoid giving user the possibility to
resize table in design mode (when contentEditable=true).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
document.designMode = "on";
document.execCommand("enableObjectResizing", false, "false");
document.execCommand("enableInlineTableEditing", false, "false");
```

In Firefox, the resizing controls on a table often appear at the same time as the inline table editing controls, so you probably really want to turn off both of them.

If your editable content is inside an iframe, be aware that changes to the CSS position of the ancestor iframe will reset the effects of these commands.

I have prepared a simplified [test page](http://chris.photobooks.com/tests/rte/moz_resizing/moz_resizing.html) that shows this solution in action.

Comment: Enabling and disabling image resizing in Firefox4 does not appear to work, per my testing, and your test page.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this; this code appears to work in my Firefox4. I notice a new caveat, however: if a resizer control is active when resizing controls are turned off, the active control will remain active and functional. Is this what you are experiencing?  If no resizer is active, are you able to turn off resizers and THEN activate a resizer?  Or are you seeing some other behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Working in Firefox4, it seems that the answer (at least for now) is 'no'.  The command referenced in Chris's answer doesn't appear to work in Firefox4, and removing the attribute or setting it to false does not remove the resize functionality from the object once it has already been selected.

Comment: I've tested my solution in Firefox 4 on two different machines, and verified that it still works as expected, exactly as it did in Firefox 3.  If you'd like to follow up for a more in-depth diagnosis, feel free to contact me; my email address is in my profile.